# SDWebImage + MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, mbprogresshud

Good day!

I use these two libraries when download full sized images from web.

CODE:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^
    {
        [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", img]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_image.jpg"]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
      [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

It turns out that the full size picture is loaded later than hiding the indicator (shown placeholder image)

What I do wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `-(void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;` instead, and put on the `completedBlock` the hiding of the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code, the line

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

is executed before the download has finished.

The method `sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` is **non-blocking thread**.

You should use the `completionBlock` of `sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:completed:` and adding your hiding method into.

> Using blocks
>
> With blocks, you can be notified about the image download progress and
>   whenever the image retrieval has completed with success or not:

*Note:* neither your success nor failure block will be call if your image request is canceled before completion.

Try this code :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
                [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", img]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_image.jpg"]
                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                        });
        }];
    });
}
```

Comment: Same thing after change code... But i found a solution! While loading the picture shows a small resolution square color background :)
Thankx anyway